# Axis2 generating ArrayStoreException

Tags: java, apache-axis

I have encountered an ArrayStoreException when parsing XML to Java Classes in the following segment of code:

```
757        StringReader in = new StringReader( xmlString );
758        XMLStreamReader reader = StAXUtils.createXMLStreamReader( in );
759
760        try
761        {
762          ManageContentRequest.Factory.parse( reader );
763        }
764        catch ( Exception e )
765        {
766          this.log.error( xmlString );
767          this.log.info( e.getLocalizedMessage(), e );
768          e.printStackTrace();
769        }
```

The stacktrace is (The ** prefixed line matches the above segment of code):

```
2011-11-21 15:37:05  INFO  com.geometryit.blis.production.Publish  -   - java.lang.ArrayStoreException
org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.ConverterUtil$ObjectConversionException: java.lang.ArrayStoreException
  at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.ConverterUtil.ConvertToArbitraryObjectArray(ConverterUtil.java:1211)
  at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.ConverterUtil.convertToArray(ConverterUtil.java:1172)
  at au.gov.business.ablis._2011_09.data.ServiceType$Factory.parse(ServiceType.java:3864)
  at au.gov.business.ablis._2011_09.messages.contentmanagement.RequestItemChoice_type0$Factory.parse(RequestItemChoice_type0.java:1202)
  at au.gov.business.ablis._2011_09.messages.contentmanagement.RequestItem_type0$Factory.parse(RequestItem_type0.java:463)
  at au.gov.business.ablis._2011_09.messages.contentmanagement.ManageContentRequest$Factory.parse(ManageContentRequest.java:544)
  **at com.geometryit.blis.production.Publish.publishLicenceUsingWebService(Publish.java:762)
  at com.geometryit.blis.production.Publish.publishCommonwealthLicence(Publish.java:616)
  at com.geometryit.blis.production.Publish.publishLicence(Publish.java:489)
  at com.geometryit.blis.production.Publish.processRequest(Publish.java:246)
  at com.geometryit.blis.AppServlet.doPost(AppServlet.java:235)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:306)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:541)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:383)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:284)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:322)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1684)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException
  at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
  at java.util.ArrayList.toArray(ArrayList.java:306)
  at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.ConverterUtil.ConvertToArbitraryObjectArray(ConverterUtil.java:1207)
  ... 27 more
```

From the wsdl and xsd files, I generated the Java classes using Axis2 v1.6.1 on Java 1.6.0_24, Windows 7, 64bit. The section of the xsd that is relevant is highlighted with a ** prefix.

```
<xs:complexType name="ServiceType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Id" type="tns:AblisId" />
    <xs:element name="TierOfGovernment" type="tns:TierOfGovernmentType" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="Jurisdiction" type="tns:JurisdictionType" minOccurs="1" />
    <xs:element name="Status" type="tns:ServiceStatusType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    <xs:element name="Type" type="tns:ServiceTypeType" />
    <xs:element name="Name" type="tns:String256"  minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="DescriptiveName" type="tns:String256" minOccurs="0" />
    <xs:element name="AlternativeName" type="tns:String256" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
    <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string"  minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="ShortDescription" type="tns:String250" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="EligibilityRequirements" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="Coverage" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="DisqualifiedPersonsOrEntities" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
    <xs:element name="Duration" type="tns:String255" minOccurs="0" />
    <xs:element name="Exemptions" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="MutualRecognition" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
    <xs:element name="OngoingEligibilityRequirements" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
    <xs:element name="StartDate" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
    <xs:element name="EndDate" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
    <xs:element name="Priority" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
    <xs:element name="ApprovedTime" type="tns:String255" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="WhenRequired" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
    <xs:element name="AdditionalInformation" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
    <xs:element name="Transfer" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
    **<xs:element name="URL" type="xs:anyURI" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    <xs:element name="VersionNumber" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
    <xs:element name="AttributeOverride" type="tns:String100" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    <xs:element name="BusinessStructure" type="tns:BusinessStructureType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    <xs:element name="TopicName" type="tns:String100" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    <xs:element name="Term" type="tns:TermDefinitionType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    <xs:element name="AssociatedService" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="ServiceId" type="tns:AblisId" />
            <xs:element name="Service" type="tns:ServiceType" />
          </xs:choice>
          <xs:element name="Type" type="tns:ServiceAssociationTypeType" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="AssociatedBusinessActivity" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" >
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="BusinessActivityCode" type="tns:BusinessActivityCodeType" />
          <xs:element name="Principal" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="AskYesNoAnswer" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="AskMultiAnswer" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="AssociatedKeyword" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="KeywordId" type="tns:AblisId" />
            <xs:element name="Keyword" type="tns:KeywordAliasType" />
          </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="AssociatedLegislation" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="LegislationId" type="tns:AblisId" />
            <xs:element name="Legislation" type="tns:LegislationType" />
          </xs:choice>
          <xs:element name="Reference" type="tns:String1024" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="AssociatedPrerequisite" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="PrerequisiteId" type="tns:AblisId" />
            <xs:element name="Prerequisite" type="tns:PrerequisiteType" />
          </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="AssociatedOrganisation" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="OrganisationId" type="tns:AblisId" />
            <xs:element name="Organisation" type="tns:OrganisationType" />
          </xs:choice>
          <xs:element name="Role" type="tns:OrganisationRoleType" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="AssociatedAnswer" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="AnswerId" type="tns:AblisId" />
            <xs:element name="Answer" type="tns:AnswerType" />
          </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I have looked at the source code for org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.ConverterUtil an understand what is going on there. The above segment of code is being executed hundreds of times (> 500). I strongly suspect that ConverterUtil.convertToArray has been called previously.

Any ideas what is going on here?

**EDIT:** The relevant section of xmlString is:

```
    <Service>
        <tns:Id>
          <tns:InternalId xsi:nil="true" />
            <tns:ExternalId>C0444</tns:ExternalId>
        </tns:Id>
        <tns:TierOfGovernment>Commonwealth</tns:TierOfGovernment>
        <tns:Jurisdiction>WA</tns:Jurisdiction>
        <tns:Status>Published</tns:Status>
        <tns:Type>Licence</tns:Type>
        <tns:Name>Certificate of Plant Breeder's Rights</tns:Name>
        <tns:DescriptiveName></tns:DescriptiveName>
        <tns:Description>You will require this certificate if you are the original breeder of a new variety of plant or if you are acquiring ownership rights from an original breeder.
This certificate will provide exclusive commercial rights to the new plant variety. It provide rights to exclude others from producing propagating material, conditioning propagating material (including cleaning, coating, sorting, packaging and grading), offering propagating material for sale, importing and exporting and stocking propagating material of protected varieties. 

Please consult the Contact Officer for further details.</tns:Description>
        <tns:EligibilityRequirements>As the applicant you must: 

- be the original breeder or have acquired legal ownership; 
- demonstrate that the plant variety is new or recently exploited and is unique (distinct, uniform, stable); and
- have an acceptable name; and
- pay the required fees.

A recently exploited variety is one which had been sold with the breeder's consent in either:

- Australia - not more than 12 months prior to lodging the application; or 
- not more than 6 years (trees and vines) or 4 years (all other species) in another country which is a member of the International Union for the Protection of New Varieties of Plants.

In order to demonstrate that the plant is distinct, uniform and stable (DUS), the applicant will be required to nominate an accredited Qualified Person (QP) as part of the application process. This person will be responsible for conducting a comparative growing trial in order to demonstrate the DUS of the plant.

Please consult the Contact Officer for further details.</tns:EligibilityRequirements>
        <tns:MutualRecognition>false</tns:MutualRecognition>
        <tns:Priority>false</tns:Priority>
        <tns:URL>http://www.ipaustralia.gov.au/get-the-right-ip/plant-breeders-rights/`</tns:URL>
        <tns:BusinessStructure>SoleTrader</tns:BusinessStructure>
  <tns:TopicName></tns:TopicName>

        <tns:AssociatedKeyword>
          <tns:Keyword>
            <tns:Id>
                <tns:InternalId xsi:nil="true" />
                <tns:ExternalId xsi:nil="true" />
            </tns:Id>
            <tns:Keyword>Breeder's</tns:Keyword>
          </tns:Keyword>
        </tns:AssociatedKeyword>
        <tns:AssociatedKeyword>
          <tns:Keyword>
            <tns:Id>
                <tns:InternalId xsi:nil="true" />
                <tns:ExternalId xsi:nil="true" />
            </tns:Id>
            <tns:Keyword>Certificate</tns:Keyword>
          </tns:Keyword>
        </tns:AssociatedKeyword>
        <tns:AssociatedKeyword>
          <tns:Keyword>
            <tns:Id>
                <tns:InternalId xsi:nil="true" />
                <tns:ExternalId xsi:nil="true" />
            </tns:Id>
            <tns:Keyword>Plant</tns:Keyword>
          </tns:Keyword>
        </tns:AssociatedKeyword>
        <tns:AssociatedKeyword>
          <tns:Keyword>
            <tns:Id>
                <tns:InternalId xsi:nil="true" />
                <tns:ExternalId xsi:nil="true" />
            </tns:Id>
            <tns:Keyword>Rights</tns:Keyword>
          </tns:Keyword>
        </tns:AssociatedKeyword>
  <tns:AssociatedOrganisation>
    <tns:OrganisationId>
              <tns:InternalId xsi:nil="true" />
                <tns:ExternalId>BDP_0</tns:ExternalId>
    </tns:OrganisationId>
    <tns:Role>Owner</tns:Role>
  </tns:AssociatedOrganisation>
    </Service>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since solved this problem. The root cause of the problem was bad data on my part. The URI that was causing the problem contained the grave accent (`). This led to a MalformedURIException being thrown but ignored. It was not even logged.

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-5190 for more information.